# How to calculate product price in woocommerce using formula

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am developing en ecommerce site for a jewellery. They need to calculate product price automatically using a formula. The following is the format of the required formula.

`(quantity * gold rate) + making charge + stone rate(if available)`

Here `gold rate` may vary frequently and `stone rate` is not mandatory.
This will also need to apply for other type of products(silver, diamond etc).
eg for silver the formula will become

`(quantity * silver rate) + making charge + stone rate(if available)`

Only the final price is need to display in site.

Also I need to set `gold rate` and `silver rate` globally, because this will be same for all gold and silver ornaments.

I found some plugins, but not found one with all these requirements.

Can someone please suggest any solution

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this? Where's your code? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor I didin't try any code yet, I am just looking for a method to start because I am a newbie in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some coding knowledge...

As you're using woocom I would go toward creating a new custom category/taxonomy called "raw material".
From there I would add all the required terms, here for instance gold, silver, diamond...etc. I would then add a custom meta field to each terms called "rate" (*).

Upon creating a new product, you would select what raw materials the item is made of, which would enable you to fetch the custom meta we created called "rate".

Then we could use a bit of JS magic to do the required calculations, and that's it. Not really hard to put in place.

But like @disinfor said, at SOF we don't code, we help and fix problems. If you want to hire someone you can try Fiverr.

---

(*) Adding custom meta to terms: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/

Comment: I didn't expect any code, but a method because this is my first wordpress project. I just worked on customization and plugins only. I will try what you suggested and let you know the result. Thank you